# Consuming an Eclipse shared license feature

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I have a license feature, say com.example.sharedlicense which contains the necessary license information. I'm trying to consume this shared license in another (regular) feature by following [this guide](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_shared_license.htm).

I think I have everything set up correctly (the consuming feature.xml looks exactly like in the guide) but when I try to install it via the generated updatesite I don't get a license prompt. No license is present in the feature metadata as well (visible when you click "More info..").

The guide at the end says

> An IU will not be created in the p2 repository for the license
>   feature, but the license text will be included in the p2 metadata.

but I can't quite grasp what will be displayed and what won't be. So I have two main questions:

- Am I using the shared license feature correctly? I expect that I can simply refer to the shared license and have it displayed during install.
- If not, how can I achieve the desired behavior without having local copies of the license in each feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your license feature is prepared correctly, you have to add  tag to your feature.xml:

```xml
<license url="%licenseURL">%license</license>
```

How to prepare license feature is explained here: http://relengofthenerds.blogspot.com/2011/01/implementing-shared-licenses-with-37m5.html

Comment: Just a clarification - %license and %licenseURL will resolve to the parameters defined in the referred shared license feature.